# Jenkins Teardown when stopping a job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This is for the Jenkins gurus out there,

Is there a way to call a teardown function when click on stop build. ?

I got a system that installs some services and does some testing. Then It stops the services and uninstalls the services as a part of tear down. Sometimes what happens is that when I click stop build from Jenkins it leaves some stray services and brakes the build server as they are already running. So then I have to kill the process and services manually which can be painful.

The work around I found was to check for the services when the build is starting and kill them before I start my tests. But It would be nicer/Cooler if my jobs can clean up after them self.

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem (not solution) is described here : [gracefull job termination](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17116) - Not solved

Your approach is a good solution. It handles cases where jenkins crashes (it does happen).  Performing a cleanup before performing the test a good step and makes overall system rugged.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a work around if anyone is interested:

I have added a post build action using the flexible publish and set the run condition to always. So Then I have a script to stop services and clean up.

This way when ever I terminate a job it calls the post build action and does its magic, In a way its a graceful termination